# Can't use HTML5 geolocation with Android 4.4

Tags: angularjs, cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing a web-app which is supposed to work on iOS and Android, and uses geolocation with HTML5.

We have tested it on Android 4.1 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2) and on several iOs versions with iOS simulator and devices, everything was fine and the `onSuccess` callback is passed,

but when we tried to test it on a *Wiko Sunset phone*, with Android 4.4.2, and *neither the success nor the fail one passed*.

When we visited some websites asking our position (such as [Mappy](http://fr.mappy.com)), we experienced a pop-up error which said that our position that it couldn't get our position, and that we should check that geolocation service was activated (which did was).

We experienced this situation with 4 browsers:

- Opera
- Firefox
- Chrome
- The native Android browser.

Is it possible to use HTML 5 geolocation API with Android 4.4?

Here is our testing Angular controller code.

```
testTTS.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
        testTTS.geolocation = false;


        var options = { 
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        };

        onSuccess = function(position) {
            alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
                  'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
                  'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
                  'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
                  'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
                  'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
                  'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
                  'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
        };

        onFail = function(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        };

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onFail, options);

}]);
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is the SO, is the device, I've made geolocation work on a nexus 7 with android 4.4

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Seems to be that indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me on android devices

```
function getGpsCordinates(callback) {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {                  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            //Success
            function (position) {
                console.log("GPS: Success");
                callback(position);
            },
            //Error
            function (error) {
                console.log("GPS: Error");
                var position = {
                  coords: {
                      longitude: 0,
                      latitude: 0,
                      speed: 0
                  }
              };
              callback(position);
            },
            { timeout: 7000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
    } else {
        var position = {
            coords: {
                longitude: 0,
                latitude: 0,
                speed: 0
            }
        };
        console.log("GPS: Not Supported");
        callback(position);
    }
    console.log("GPS: Continued");
}

getGpsCordinates(function(mycallback) {
  alert(mycallback.coords.latitude);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try asap.

Comment: So @BillRousseau any news on this ?